# Taking the first JSON string that contains a specific phrase (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, parsing

I am trying to get the value of the first string in JSON containing the string `amogus`. I have no idea how to start.

I want it to get the first JSON string that has `amogus` in it, then take the entire string, including the number included in the found string.

JSON file:

```
{stuff: ["hosds29083", "amogus1208", "amogus1213"]
```

As you can see, the JSON file contains multiple strings, and some of them contain `amogus`. My desired output is `amogus1208`, which is the first string containing `amogus`.

Does anybody know how this could be done? Thanks.

Comment: You may look at [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: And also look at [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz could you show me how to get the first string containing `amogus`? I tried working around with it but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the JSON content into an array then use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first matching item and use [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check the items in the callback function in `find()`, as follows:

```js
const data = ["hosds29083", "amogus1208", "amogus1213"];

const firstOne = data.find(str => str.includes('amogus'));

console.log(firstOne)
```